# Crash after package execution (npm)

Tags: typescript, npm, vite

I am trying to include a package to a TypeScript project I cloned and have been working on for a while that is using Vite.
I am trying to install [node-scp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-scp) using the install command, `npm install node-scp`

Install was successful, but when I am trying to use a sample code in my program I am crashing. When I add this code:

```js
 import { Client } from 'node-scp';

const onReject = () => {
    Client({
        host: inputs.ipadress, //remote host ip 
        port: 22, //port used for scp 
        username: inputs.username, //username to authenticate
        password: inputs.password, //password to authenticate
    }).then(client => {
        client.uploadDir('./local/dir', '/server/path')
           .then(response => {
            client.close()
           })
           .catch(error => {})
       }).catch(e => console.log(e))
};
```

The error I am getting is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/node-scp.js?v=2b2c4f4f net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

and the website does not load.

I did some googling but found nothing relevant to my issue. When I remove the code snippet from my code, the website loads.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a server running on `localhost:3000`?

Comment: Yes, I am running dev env locally to test it. without adding the code snippet the website was loading on localhost perfectly fine.. But after adding the newly installed package it crashes..

Comment: It sounds like there's an error accessing the module. It looks like your bundler is not copying `/node_modules/.vite/deps/node-scp.js` to the target, but I'm not sure why that would result in a 504 instead of a 404.